# Peer verifying with libcurl and SSL

Tags: c, windows, ssl, https, libcurl

I'm POSTing data to a HTTPS server using libcurl compiled with openssl using Visual Studio 2008 in windows and it all works fine with CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER set to 0. I've tried following http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html and just about every "SSL and SECURITY OPTIONS" option in the manual. I'm wondering what the right combination of options is and what the certificate file should look like.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about how to extract CA Certs from [official site](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)